# Using linkedin api, can i search profiles for "open to work" then create targeted ads to those profiles?

Tags: linkedin-api

Using linkedin api, can i search profiles for "open to work" then create targeted ads to those profiles?

I have tried consulting linkedin but they do not have a way to target those "open to work"

Answer (score 0):

No, right now, it is not allowed by Linkedin. Right now, LinkedIn gives only the scope of r_liteprofile and r_emailaddress to Retrieve authenticated member's name, headline, photo, and member's primary email address.

To get the relevant candidate for the job, you may need to check open_to_work status, skills, projects, etc, for that you need the permission of r_fullprofile,

LinkedIn API has restricted such information as per their documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/full-profile
[image]

As per their documentation, to access the information of skills, address, etc, your app needs to request r_fullprofile. But they have closed it now and no alternate is given. The more detail about the current permissions from LinkedIn can be seen here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access

Right now there are currently in development mode. They are working on developing their APIs. What and when they will release such information is not available to document right now.